# Current time in sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, date-time

I create a workflow in SharePoint designer 2010. For each task I have to create a event in a calendar. To get a current date and time I modify list item and use "Pause for 1 min" (without pause, variable with modified time won't update).

Can I make it in a different way, without using pause or modify list?

Comment: Consider the following: Data source: Workflow context, Field from source: Date and Time Started, Return field as: as Date/Time.

Comment: This will give me a time when following action whas started? For me it would be create item in calendar list. Did I understand that well? If yes it will be helpful for my "end time". How I will be able to get a time and date for "start time" (time when task was assigned) ?

Comment: It will be the time that the workflow started -- which will work unless it's AFTER an approval process or other decision point actions.

Comment: So I think it won't help in my case. Time of workflow start gives me nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Or maybe I don't understand how to use it?